# rkhunter warnings: SSH protocol v1 + SSH root access allowed, fix?

Tags: ssh, security, rkhunter

How can I solve the following `rkhunter` warnings?:

```
Checking if SSH root access is allowed                   [ Warning ]
Checking if SSH protocol v1 is allowed                   [ Warning ]
```

and what do they mean?

Please, take into account that I'm a newbie with a fresh installation of openSUSE Leap 15.3 KDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocol version 1 has been deprecated, so I will answer the other half of this question only.

The root access via SSH can be dangerous, if anywhere else than on a local network, where it actually can be very useful for managing stuff without passwords.

Make sure first, that you had set up your public key, which how-to you can find all over the place or the internet for that matter, so I omit it.

---

Once you had exchanged your public key with the server you will be connecting to, be sure to just test if password-less SSH login works, and then you may edit with `sudo` or as superuser the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the target machine to contain the following:

```
# allow my public key only, never a password
PubkeyAuthentication    yes
PasswordAuthentication  no
AuthenticationMethods   publickey
PermitRootLogin         prohibit-password
```

The above will make sure no passwords are to be tried and also `root` can be accessed via SSH directly.

---

Now to harden the security if you rented a VPS (virtual private server) someplace you do not have physical access, it is usually wise to disable `root` access, and use some *ordinary* `sudo`er, and changing SSH port or other less known techniques.

---

Recommended know-how sources to read:

- [My question on Security SE here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/154076/82570)
- [Discussion on Security SE under my question here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/179114/82570)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the options:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
Protocol 1,2
```

To:

```
PermitRootLogin no
Protocol 2
```

Answer (score -2):

I have:

```
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```